# Looking for php5 equivalent syntax of php7 functions

Tags: php

I am in desperate need to find the php5 equivalent for the following functions:

The following error is returned for the below function:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

**NOT WORKING EXAMPLE OF BOOL**

```
    private function isFile($data): bool
    {
        return file_exists($data);
    }
```

I am able to work around this error by removing part of the function `: bool` but i'm not sure if that's the right way or if that will cause unexpected issues.

**WORKING**

```
    private function isFile($data)
    {
        return file_exists($data);
    }
```

I've got a couple of these php7 functions that end with `: bool` or `: void` or `: array` or `: string` and none of these work in php5.6, however, if I remove the column and everything after it then the code works, would like confirmation removing those bits is correct or is there a php 5.6 substitute code for the parts removed.

Further examples

**NOT WORKING EXAMPLE OF VOID**

```
    private function handleElementClose(Stream $stream): void
    {
        // Skip '</'
        $stream->next(2);
        $element = $stream->readTo('>');

        // Skip '>'
        $stream->next();
        $this->closeElement($stream, $element);
    }
```

Comment: That just specifies the return type. PHP5 doesn't care about them so remove the type statements and let it carry on. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: (Also, stop using PHP 5, which was end-of-lifed nearly three years ago and is no longer safe to use.)

Comment: This sounds like a X/Y problem, why do refactor your code to old syntax instead of using a newer php version?

Comment: No-one should be using php5 any more if they can possibly help it, let alone writing new code targeted specifically at it

Comment: because i have a ton of code libraries that only work on php5 and i am not skilled enough to convert them all to php7

Comment: Good old php 5.6) Pretty much any project can be moved from 5.6 to 7.2 without any or much refactoring. I speak from some experience. Rewriting libraries or finding new ones will be more pain, but that's how it is. Php 5 is not safe. I am using 7.2 which is also end of life, and my situation is not much better - Zend 1.12 Framework(end of life - not my choise) which can't be moved to 7.3 or 7.4. Not talking about 8.0

Comment: is there any online code conversion tools that help migrating code compatible with php 7+?

Comment: @user3436467 Not really. There are some compatibility checkers out there, or coding standard checkers etc. They probably will help you track down most of the stuff you have to change, but not all of it. Some of the errors you will only find by testing and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` It's a long and hard road of moving the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function file_exists returns a bool value. So removing `:bool` must be correct.
Here is a substitution, considering the unexpected errors because of the return values.

```
private function isFile($data)
{
    return (bool) file_exists($data);
}
```

Comment: i just added a example of `: void` is the solution the same?

Comment: There's no need for the typecast, since `file_exists()` always returns `bool`.

Comment: @user3436467 Yes, the solution is the same -- just remove `:void`

Comment: @user3436467 Just remove for :void instead of typecast.

Comment: thank you @barmar devstorm21